# How can I make fields in Object as required or do field validation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsonschema

Let's assume I have a class created by using jsonschemapojo2 as so

```
public class a{
   private String  b;
   public void setB(String b){this.b = b}
   public void getB(){return b}
}
```

I used this class to parse a result from mongodb into an object:

```
a = {b : "1"}
```

The new requirement I have for my application is that an exception must be thrown when the field b  is null, empty string or it's not present in the object. I can't use annotations at the class level as the class is created from the jsonschemapojo2. Is there any way to specify the required field annotation at the schema level?. Otherwise how would I create a proxy method that validates the object? should I use reflection or is there a smarter way to do it in springboot?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either one from bellow options to define the constraints -

i) By the programmatic API [More Details](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-api)

ii) By XML : [More details](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-mapping-xml-constraints)

You can’t enable or disable constraints therefore you would have to redefine the metadata at every runtime, which is not a good idea.

Comment: how can I set not empty constraint at the jsonchemapojo2 level

Comment: There is a tag for it : `<constraint annotation="jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, bean  validation allows to define the constraints in xml file. You can find many examples at Hibernate website.